# Need help using HTML Font Style

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need some help with my code
How do I use this font style - "brandon grotesque".
I can't seem to change the font style as I don't how to insert
this font style into my code.
Below is my code:

```
<style>
footer{ 
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height:100px;
margin-top:-100px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px;
background-color: lightgrey;

}

</style>

<body>



<footer>
<div>
<p style="font-size: 30px; text-align:center;">&copy; Copyright 2020, SCOPE 
Industries Berhad</p>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you load the font? Through a link or downloaded asset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
footer{ 
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-family: 'any_font_name_you_imported', sans-serif !important;
}
```

Example:

```
<html>
      <head>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
          family=Noto+Sans+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
       <body>
             <footer>
                  <h1>Hii</h1>
             </footer>
       </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Read the edits, in your main index.html or the current HTML file that you are trying to change the font.

Comment: No problem dude, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try including `font-family: 'brandon grotesque'` into your `footer` css class. I'm not sure if it has to be capitalised correctly, but try to make sure it is just in case.

Also try not to define `footer` twice. It is unnecessary.

Edit:
Capitalisation does not matter, and it doesn't seem to work oops. But maybe this link will help: https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Comment: Check the capitalisation?

Comment: sorry dude then i do not know. good luck solving the problem tho

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the font file into CSS via @font-face, I think the problem here is you did not add the font files for the browser. You should add the file of font first then you can define the font added into CSS.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(brandon_grotesque.woff);
}
```

Comment: Need to add this to the style part?

Comment: yes, I think the font you add is the custom font. The browser can not read it.
More information:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Comment: Ah yes, henry is able to help me with that part. Problem solved already. Thanks for the help